# Lua return directory path from path

Tags: lua

I have string variable which represents the full path of some file, like:

`x = "/home/user/.local/share/app/some_file"` on Linux
or
`x = "C:\\Program Files\\app\\some_file"` on Windows

I'm wondering if there is some programmatic way, better then splitting string manually to get to directory path

How do I return directory path (path without filename) in Lua, without loading additional library like LFS, as I'm using Lua extension from other application?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In plain Lua, there is no better way. Lua has nothing working on paths. You'll have to use pattern matching. This is all in the line of the mentality of offering tools to do much, but refusing to include functions that can be replaced with one-liners:

```
-- onelined version ;)
--    getPath=function(str,sep)sep=sep or'/'return str:match("(.*"..sep..")")end
getPath=function(str,sep)
    sep=sep or'/'
    return str:match("(.*"..sep..")")
end

x = "/home/user/.local/share/app/some_file"
y = "C:\\Program Files\\app\\some_file"
print(getPath(x))
print(getPath(y,"\\"))
```

Comment: OK, thanks for your confirmation that there is no ready-made function and thanks for your snippet. Cheers

Comment: That function should not really be a one-liner

Comment: No need for the last part of the pattern because `*` is greedy. You can also avoid the explicit capture. So `".*"..sep` should suffice.

Comment: Thanks, edited accordingly. @kikito, yeah probably would be better on 4 lines, but my point is it is only one line that is actually really functional. The others are just a piece of plumbing.

Comment: Unless passing a Windows path to external utilities, you can use forward slashes for either Linux or Windows.  And that simplifies your function to function getPath(str)
  return str:gsub('\\','/'):match('.*/')
end

Comment: You can easily get the OS's path separator with `package.config:sub(1,1)`, by making the separator argument optional with a default value of the OS's path separator, you can simplify the function to accept only one argument, the path string.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a platform independent and simpler solution based on jpjacobs solution:

```
function getPath(str)
    return str:match("(.*[/\\])")
end

x = "/home/user/.local/share/app/some_file"
y = "C:\\Program Files\\app\\some_file"
print(getPath(x)) -- prints: /home/user/.local/share/app/
print(getPath(y)) -- prints: C:\Program Files\app\
```

Comment: on Unix systems file names can have backslashes in them, only the NUL and forward slash characters are forbidden. so this code fails if instead of "some_file" the basename is for example "some\file", it would return a dirname that ends with part of the basename (e.g "...same\" in the "same\file" basename example). so you shouldn't have both forward and backslash in your pattern and use the OS's path separator character which can easily be gotten with `package.config:sub(1,1)`.

Comment: @Wis Oh... And any suggestion on how to make it more bullet proof without complicating it too much? Because its simplicity was preciselly what I liked more about this method... Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For something like this, you can just write your own code. But there are also libraries in pure Lua that do this, like [lua-path](https://github.com/moteus/lua-path) or [Penlight](https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight/blob/master/lua/pl/path.lua).