# Unexpected lua pattern matching result

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

For the following code:

```
local function getParentPath(_path)

    pattern = "(.+)([/\\][/\\])(.+)"
    i,j,k = string.match(path,pattern)
    return i,j,k

end

print(getParentPath(path))
```

For path = "C://data//file.text", I get:

```
C://data // file.text
```

But For path = "C:\data\file.text", I get:

```
nil nil nil
```

I am looking for a pattern which woks for both. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you elaborate in more details what did you expect to match? Everything up to last `//`? There's two of them in your string and it is not clear what you really want just from one example.

Comment: sorry I re framed my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the first `.+` matches greedily and grabs all up to the last `\` and then backtracks. Then, one `\` can be matched with `[\\/]`, and thus the first group has one backslash, and the second has got the second.

You can fix it by using

```
pattern = "^(.-)([/\\]+)([^/\\]+)$"
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/QwDNPJ)

Explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.-)` - any characters but as few as possible (lazy matching with `-` quantifier)
- `([/\\]+)` - 1+ `/` or `\`
- `([^/\\]+)` - 1+ characters other than `/` and `\`
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Also, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102126/lua-return-directory-path-from-path

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly expected. First greedy `(.+)` matches as many symbols as it can without breaking following patterns - i.e. everything up to very last slash that is necessary to make `([/\\]+)` match.